# Multiple discriminator value for the same entity in Doctirne

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it possible to have different discriminator values for one entity? That is :

```
Dog => Animal,
Cat => Animal,
Shark => Fish
```

I tried to do somethig like

```
/**
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type_animal", type="string", length=50)
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"Dog"="Animal", "Cat"="Animal", "Shark"="Fish"})
 */
```

but it didn't work.

I would never do like this but I have a database shared by two applications and it is necessary to implement this logic.

Comment: Just give it a try - I did not find anything in the docs which is speaking against it.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. How could Doctrine guess what class to use when fetching data from database?

Comment: @JakubMatczak, discriminator values *Dog* and *Cat* result in Animal class and *Shark* in Fish class. So as long as there's no need to differentiate classes for Dog and Cat it shouldn't be an issue conceptually.

Comment: Oh, I thought it's the other way. My mistake. :) Anyway, it still would be an issue, because discriminator value is not kept in entity instance, so Doctrine would not know what discriminator value to assign when saving data into database.